# Настройка удалённого подключения

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Есть последовательность команд:

```
- cmd1
- cmd2
- cmd3
```

Сейчас приходится делать так:

```
- ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p $SSH_PORT $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3"
```

Хочется что-то типа такого:

```
- ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p $SSH_PORT $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST
- cmd1 
- cmd2 
- cmd3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 

Можно иметь скрипт `remote-commands.sh`, грузить его на удалённый хост через `scp` и потом исполнять через `ssh`

2.

`remote-ssh`

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p $SSH_PORT $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "$@"
```

потом в `gitlab-ci.yml`

```
- chmod +x remote-ssh
- remote-ssh cmd1 param1
- remote-ssh cmd2 param1 param2
- remote-ssh cmd3
```

Правда, с экранированием кавычек и пайпов тут будут нюансы

Comment: Так не подходит. Неудобно отлаживаться. Все команды выполняются скопом и гитлаб это воспринимает так же.

Comment: второй способ по одной выполняет

Answer (score 0):

вот именно так нельзя, конечно.

но можно «примерно так», если вынести список команд в отдельную переменную, значение которой будет содержать переводы строки, и, следовательно, будет корректно понято интерпретатором (например, `sh`) при чтении списка из *stdin* (благодаря наличию опции `-`) именно как набор отдельных команд:

```
variables:
    var1: |
        cmd1
        cmd2
        cmd3
build:
    script:
        - echo "${var1}" | ssh ... sh -
```

«хитрость» тут в использовании [блочного литерала `|`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F), в котором сохраняются символы перевода строк.

Comment: Так не подходит. Неудобно отлаживаться. Все команды выполняются скопом и гитлаб это воспринимает так же.

Comment: ну так напишите три отдельные команды в блоке script. и вопрос переформулируйте: там про это ни слова. особенно заголовок.